# mutltiple active Bluetooth connection connectivity android

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is it possible to connect a android mobile bluetooth with multiple bluetooth devices. And I need all the connection active at the same time and can transfer data at same time too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You can connect the phone with up to 7 devices (in theory).  They form a 'piconet' with the phone as the master.

If the phone initiates the connection to the first two devices then it will likely be the master (as necessary).

If you find that you are having problems connecting more then one or two devices then you should root your phone, and run 'hcitool' to determine which are slave and which is master.

Come to think of it, Nexus devices just got a new Bluetooth stack in 4.2 and I don't know if it supports hcitool.  If not, hopefully they have created an alternative.